# Fill missing values based on condition in duplicated column

Tags: python, pandas, replace, missing-data

I have Pandas dataframe with two columns, such as:

```
df = ID state
      255 NJ
      255 NaN
      266 CT
      266 CT
      277 NaN
      277 NY
      277 NaN
```

I want to fill missing values in `state`.

Desired output is the following:

```
df = ID state
      255 NJ
      255 NJ
      266 CT
      266 CT
      277 NY
      277 NY
      277 NY
```

How can I overcome this? Trying but without success. Tried, `numpy.where` creating masks but getting this error `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (26229,) (2053,) ()` and many more. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html):

```
df['state'] = df.sort_values('state').groupby('ID')['state'].ffill()
print (df)
    ID state
0  255    NJ
1  255    NJ
2  266    CT
3  266    CT
4  277    NY
5  277    NY
6  277    NY
```

If necessary filling multiple columns use:

```
cols = ['state', ...]
df.loc[:, cols] = df.sort_values('state').groupby('ID')[cols].ffill()
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, each `ID` has a unique `state`, so:

```
df['state'] = df.groupby('ID')['state'].transform('first')
```

output:

```
    ID state
0  255    NJ
1  255    NJ
2  266    CT
3  266    CT
4  277    NY
5  277    NY
6  277    NY
```

Answer (score 1):

first [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then use ffill using groupby

```
df.sort_values(by=['ID','state'],ascending=[True,True],inplace=True)
df['state'] = df.groupby(['ID']).transform(pd.Series.ffill)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` with `ffill` +`bfill`

```
df.state=df.groupby('ID').state.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
df
Out[907]: 
    ID state
0  255    NJ
1  255    NJ
2  266    CT
3  266    CT
4  277    NY
5  277    NY
6  277    NY
```